# How to filter and sum cells in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of families invited to my wedding, formatted like this

```
Name  | Who invited  | How much will come? 
------------------------------------------
Johes | Bride        | 2
Smits | Groom        | 3
...
```

And I want to add two cells that will come totals for "How much will come?" for Bride and for Groom separately. Is there any way to do this using formulas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following formula will do that.

### Formula

```
=QUERY(A1:C3, "SELECT A, SUM(C) GROUP BY A PIVOT B")
```

### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: This is just awesome! Almost SQL. Actually I wanted totals to split costs, so what I needed was "SELECT A, SUM(C) GROUP BY A", but thanks for showing me that QUERY function.